# CSS: How to enforce width inside a dynamic width container?

Tags: css

First off, here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u8v3rgyt/1/

The basic scenario is this: I have some text, which will vary in length.  Below this text I have a column of (**EDIT:** a varying number of) buttons, which also have text that varies.  What I want is for the text to control the overall width, and then have the button column adjust its width/its buttons' width in response.  In other words, for two different sizes of text, I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
// Short text
La la la la
[Button 1
  text]
[Button 2
  with long
  text]

// Longer text
La la la la la la la la la la
[Button 1 text]
[Button 2 with long text]
```

but I get:

```
// Short text
La la la la
[Button 1 text]
[Button 2 with long text]
```

I feel like I'm close, but I can't get the button container to have the correct width (and thus I can't limit my buttons' width).  Or rather, I can, but to do so I have to put a fixed width on the text, and that doesn't work because I need the whole thing to adjust it's size based on the text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the buttons to be as wide as the longest button? I am very cunfused

Comment: Yes, sorry (although I can't even get the overall pattern to work, with or without equal-length buttons).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want the text to dictate the width of the area in which the buttons are laid out. Using the CSS3 flex box model you could do something along these lines:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

button {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Some text blah blah blah, blah blah blah</p>
  <div class="inner">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea ... but unfortunately in this case the number of buttons is dyanmic too :(

Comment: I've edited the fiddle/answer so it's not anymore dependent on the number of buttons - please check again

Comment: I hadn't even heard of `flex` or `flex-grow`, but caniuse.com says they're supported, so ... awesome.  I don't have time to try the solution tonight, but I'm going to try it as soon as I come in the morning.  Thanks!

Comment: I just looked at your fiddle again, and I realized there's a problem: all of the buttons are in a row now, not a column :(

Comment: What browser & version are you using? It might not support display: flex;